# Reading from a USB keyboard in python with a timeout

Tags: python, keyboard, raspberry-pi

How can my Python script (started via SSH) read a single line from the connected USB keyboard?
It should do this with a timeout.

I have a card reader acting as a keyboard that sends the card ID as a single line when a card is detected.
Using `cat /dev/tty0` in a shell worked well, but I'm looking for a method to do this in my Python script.

Answer (score 0):

The data is most likely coming across as an HID-protocol USB device.  You can use the PYUSB module from sourceforge to get access to the raw data, then interpret it.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0abc, idProduct=0x0123)
if dev is None: raise ValueError("Device not found")
dev.set_configuration()
endpoint = device[0][(0,0)][0]
for attempts in xrange(10):
    try:
        data = device.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress, endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
    except:
        data = None
if data is None: raise RuntimeError("no data found")
print 'got data', data
```

You need permission to access the device.  It will raise an exception on timeout